# How to use CustomMultiChildLayout & CustomSingleChildLayout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can someone with experience in using [`CustomSingleChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomSingleChildLayout-class.html) and [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) classes be able to explain in detail (with examples) in how to use them.

I am new to Flutter and am trying to understand how to use these. However, the documentation is horrible and is not clear. I tried to scour the internet for examples, but there aren't any other documentation.

I would be eternally grateful if you could help.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please add in what you want to use them for?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Do not worry about this as I am writing an extensive answer.

Comment: High expectations then!

Comment: @JoãoSoares Done, let me know if you have any corrections.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot That would be very unlikely. I've seen your answers before. Great answer, as always.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

First of all, I want to say that I am glad to help you with this as I can understand your struggles - there are benefits to figuring it out by yourself as well (the documentation is amazing).

What `CustomSingleChildLayout` does will be obvious after I explained `CustomMultiChildLayout` to you.

### [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html)

The point of this widget is allowing you to **layout** the children you pass to this widget in a single function, i.e. their positions and sizes can depend on each other, which is something you *cannot achieve* using e.g. the prebuilt `Stack` widget.

```dart
CustomMultiChildLayout(
  children: [
    // Widgets you want to layout in a customized manner
  ],
)
```

Now, there are **two more steps** you need to take before you can start laying out your children:

1. Every child you pass to `children` needs to be a [`LayoutId`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutId-class.html) and you pass the widget you actually want to show as a child to that `LayoutId`. The `id` will uniquely identify your widgets, making them accessible when laying them out:

```dart
CustomMultiChildLayout(
  children: [
    LayoutId(
      id: 1, // The id can be anything, i.e. any Object, also an enum value.
      child: Text('Widget one'), // This is the widget you actually want to show.
    ),
    LayoutId(
      id: 2, // You will need to refer to that id when laying out your children.
      child: Text('Widget two'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

2. You need to create a [`MultiChildLayoutDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate-class.html) subclass that handles the layout part. The documentation here seems to be very elaborate.

```dart
class YourLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  // You can pass any parameters to this class because you will instantiate your delegate
  // in the build function where you place your CustomMultiChildLayout.
  // I will use an Offset for this simple example.

  YourLayoutDelegate({this.position});

  final Offset position;
}
```

Now, all the setup is done and you can start implementing the actual layout. There are three methods you can use for that:

- [`hasChild`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/hasChild.html), which lets you check whether a particular **id** (remember `LayoutId`?) was passed to the `children`, i.e. if a child of that id is present.
- [`layoutChild`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/layoutChild.html), which you need to call for every **id**, every child, provided *exactly once* and it will give you the `Size` of that child.
- [`positionChild`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/positionChild.html), which allows you to change the position from `Offset(0, 0)` to any offset you specify.

I feel like the concept should be pretty clear now, which is why I will illustrate how to implement a delegate for the example `CustomMultiChildLayout`:

```dart
class YourLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  YourLayoutDelegate({this.position});

  final Offset position;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    // `size` is the size of the `CustomMultiChildLayout` itself.

    Size leadingSize = Size.zero; // If there is no widget with id `1`, the size will remain at zero.
    // Remember that `1` here can be any **id** - you specify them using LayoutId.
    if (hasChild(1)) {
      leadingSize = layoutChild(
        1, // The id once again.
        BoxConstraints.loose(size), // This just says that the child cannot be bigger than the whole layout.
      );
      // No need to position this child if we want to have it at Offset(0, 0).
    }

    if (hasChild(2)) {
      final secondSize = layoutChild(
        2,
        BoxConstraints(
          // This is exactly the same as above, but this can be anything you specify.
          // BoxConstraints.loose is a shortcut to this.
          maxWidth: size.width,
          maxHeight: size.height,
        ),
      );

      positionChild(
        2,
        Offset(
          leadingSize.width, // This will place child 2 to the right of child 1.
          size.height / 2 - secondSize.height / 2, // Centers the second child vertically.
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Two other examples are the one from the documentation (check preparation *step 2*) and a *real world* example I wrote some time back for the [`feature_discovery`](https://pub.dev/packages/feature_discovery) package: [`MultiChildLayoutDelegate` implementation](https://github.com/ayalma/feature_discovery/blob/e8a0ae2a6c1bc60d6225e5c3ee7ad82095655512/lib/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart) and [`CustomMultiChildLayout` in the `build` method](https://github.com/ayalma/feature_discovery/blob/master/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart#L574).

The last step is overriding the [`shouldRelayout` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/shouldRelayout.html), which simple controls whether `performLayout` should be called again at any given point in time by comparing to an old delegate, (optionally you can also override [`getSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/getSize.html)) and adding the delegate to your `CustomMultiChildLayout`:

```dart
class YourLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  YourLayoutDelegate({this.position});

  final Offset position;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    // ... (layout code from above)
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(YourLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.position != position;
  }
}
```

```dart
CustomMultiChildLayout(
  delegate: YourLayoutDelegate(position: Offset.zero),
  children: [
    // ... (your children wrapped in LayoutId's)
  ],
)
```

#### Considerations

- I used `1` and `2` as the **id**s in this example, but using an `enum` is probably the best way to handle the ids if you have specific ids.
- You can pass a `Listenable` to `super` (e.g. `super(relayout: animation)`) if you want to animate the layout process or trigger it based on a listenable in general.

### [`CustomSingleChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomSingleChildLayout-class.html)

[The documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) explains what I described above really well and here you will also see why I said that `CustomSingleChildLayout` will be very obvious after understanding how `CustomMultiChildLayout` works:

> [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of a multiple widgets. To control the layout of a single child, [CustomSingleChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomSingleChildLayout-class.html) is more appropriate.

This also means that using `CustomSingleChildLayout` follows the same principles I described above, but without any ids because there is only a single child.
You need to use a [`SingleChildLayoutDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SingleChildLayoutDelegate-class.html) instead, which has different methods for implementing the layout (they all have default behavior, so they are technically all optional to **override**):

- [`getConstraintsForChild`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SingleChildLayoutDelegate/getConstraintsForChild.html), which is equivalent to the constraints I passed to `layoutChild` above.
- [`getPositionForChild`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SingleChildLayoutDelegate/getPositionForChild.html), which is equivalent to `positionChild` above.

Everything else is exactly the same (remember that you do not need `LayoutId` and only have a single child instead of `children`).

---

#### [`MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MultiChildRenderObjectWidget-class.html)

This is what `CustomMultiChildLayout` is built on.
Using this requires even deeper knowledge about Flutter and is again a bit more complicated, but it is the better option if you want more customization because it is even lower level. This has one **major** advantage over `CustomMultiChildLayout` (generally, there is more control):

*`CustomMultiChildLayout` **cannot size** itself **based on its children*** (see [issue regarding better documentation for the reasoning](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18426)).

I will not explain how to use `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget` here for obvious reasons, but if you are interested, you can check out [my submission to the Flutter Clock challenge](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/clock) after January 20, 2020, in which I use `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget` extensively - you can also read [an article about this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/pure-flutterclock-face-every-line-customly-drawn-with-pixel-perfect-control-c27cba427801), which should explain a bit of how all of it works.

For now you can remember that `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget` is what makes `CustomMultiChildLayout` possible and using it directly will give you some nice benefits like not having to use `LayoutId` and instead being able to access the `RenderObject`'s parent data directly.

#### Fun fact

I wrote all the code in plain text (in the StackOverflow text field), so if there are errors, please point them out to me and I will fix them.

Comment: Wow. Amazing answer. Should the `LayoutId` be unique globally or locally? globally i.e. do sibling widgets of type `CustomMultiChildLayout` require having distinct `LayoutId`'s in their children.

Comment: @om-ha Locally - the id will be stored in the parent data of `LayoutId`, which means that this data, the id, will only be accessed by the direct parent :)

Comment: WOW! You are my savior! THIS IS WHAT I AM TALKING ABOUT! this is how the flutter documentation should be!! There was no way I would have been able to figure out how these classes worked with just the normal documentation. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Amazing answer really. `CustomMultiChildLayout` is so useful in scenarios where you need to group auto-resize multiple Text widgets within a `Column` of `Row`'s, for an example.

Comment: Great answer! How can I control in what z-position the layouts are drawn? I want a stack behavior using CustomMultiChildLayout (Stack does not work for specific reasons), but it gets drawn in the wrong stack order. The order I call layoutChild() does not seem to matter.

Comment: The solution to my question was easy: It's the order the are added in the CustomMultiChildLayout's children that determine the z-order! :)

Comment: @Otziii In fact, it is the order *painting* which determines the z-order. For CustomMultiChildLayout, the paint order is the same as the children list. However, there is no actual guarantee that it will behave this way all the time, because someone can implement a RenderObject that paints in reverse order, for example.