# Using the height of a row's tallest child as the height of the whole row in a grid

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I have a bunch of cards with varying heights, and I'd like to display them in a grid, where the row height is the height of the row's tallest widget, like so:

```
╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗
║    ║║    ║║    ║║    ║
║    ║╚════╝║    ║║    ║
╚════╝      ║    ║╚════╝
            ╚════╝
╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗
║    ║║    ║║    ║║    ║
║    ║║    ║╚════╝║    ║
╚════╝║    ║      ║    ║
      ║    ║      ╚════╝
      ╚════╝
╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗╔════╗
║    ║║    ║║    ║║    ║
║    ║╚════╝║    ║║    ║
╚════╝      ╚════╝║    ║
                  ╚════╝
```

How can I do this? I'd prefer not to use third-party packages; `flutter_staggered_grid_view`, for example, has a critical bug related to window resizing making it unusable for me.

Comment: Reviewers: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048574, which is about using the height of the tallest item in the whole grid for each row. I want to use the tallest item in each row, not the whole grid.

Comment: what about built-in `GridView`  (or `ListView` with `Row` items)?

Comment: @pskink As far as I know, `GridView` cannot do this. I'm looking into `ListView` and `Row` now, but I'd need to use `LayoutBuilder` for sizing and that's not very performant.

Comment: I can use `Wrap`, but this doesn't allow for any flexibility in the widths without using `LayoutBuilder` (a regular `GridView` can be used with upper and lower child width bounds), and performance isn't great as there's no `Wrap.builder` and I have a lot of items.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `ListView + Row`. Remember to set **crossAxisAlignment** to start and **mainAxisSize** to min

[image]

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class CustomGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final r = math.Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('123'),
          _aRow(4),
          _aRow(4),
          _aRow(4),
          _aRow(4),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _aRow(int count){
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: List.generate(count, (index) => Expanded(child: _child())),
    );
  }

  Widget _child(){
    final h = r.nextDouble()*150;
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: h,
      color: Colors.grey,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this using a `ListView` with `Row`s, utilising `ListView.builder` for decent performance.

`LayoutBuilder`, along with `package::quiver`'s [`partition` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/partition.html), is used to calculate width to achieve behaviour similar to a `GridView` with a `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent`.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    // Set minimum and maximum item width bounds.
    const minimumItemWidth = 200.0;
    const maximumItemWidth = 270.0;

    // Divide the maximum available width by the minimum item width to determine
    // the maximum amount of items that can fit in one row.
    //
    // If there's less than the minimum item width available, just use 1 item per
    // row.
    final itemsPerRow = constraints.maxWidth <= minimumItemWidth
        ? 1
        : constraints.maxWidth ~/ minimumItemWidth;

    // Partition the data into rows.
    final rows = quiver
        .partition(data, itemsPerRow)
        .toList(growable: false);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: rows.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Row(
          children: rows[index]
              .map((data) => SizedBox(
                  // Size row items to their maximum available width, constrained
                  // by the maximum width constant.
                  width: min(constraints.maxWidth / itemsPerRow, maximumItemWidth),
                  child: Tile(data: data),
              )).toList(growable: false),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```