# Tight wrap a long text around a container

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How to tight wrap a long text around a container. MS word has a tight wrap feature. I needed my text to be wrapped around the bottom container so that it looks like the image uploaded.

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4, left: 4),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
                // color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.10),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(3, 3),
                  )
                ]),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "we pay close attention to every detail",
                    style: TextStyle(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: new Text(
                      "A really long text",
                      style: TextStyle(),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 48,
            width: 48,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Color.fromRGBO(196, 196, 196, 1),
              // color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

The output I get is:

[image: My output]

I need the output like this:

[image: Required output]

Comment: IMHO, with the set of predefined widgets available this is not possible yet, to the best of my knowledge. However I would suggest you check the `CustomMultiChildLayout` widget as explained in detail in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483051/how-to-use-custommultichildlayout-customsinglechildlayout-in-flutter). Bring up a some working model and then we can try and fix the issues.

Comment: Also check `RichText` widget which allows you emebed any widget with multiple text spans and its relevant issues in github to get an idea what is and not possible with this widget right now. I have put an example for you [here](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/abZadMw) in codepen. You or someone else can try and build up on it maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this package can help you [drop_cap_text](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text)

```
DropCapText(
loremIpsumText,
style: TextStyle(
    height: 1.3,
    fontFamily: 'times',
),
dropCapChars: 2,
indentation: Offset(25, 10),
),
```

Comment: This is definitely not my use case. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around to achieve this UI. I have used a `Column` widget & inside it, I have placed a `Text` widget & a `Row` widget. The long text is divided into two separate `Text` widgets. One is above the `Row` widget & the other one is inside the `Row` widget.

Inside the `Row` widget, there is a transparent `Container` which gives us the wrapping of `Text` & this whole widget is inside the `Stack` widget.

[image: The Layout of Widgets]

Its really difficult to explain this in words so here is my implementation:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
              Card(
                elevation: 4,
                shadowColor: Colors.black45,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'we pay close attention to every detail',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          // Hidden Widget to force text wrapping
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 6),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: const Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed dolor eiusm tempor incid ut labore et dolorend magnaber aliqua.  adipis elit, sed do eius tepor incid ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              ),
                              maxLines: 4,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 16,
                bottom: -16,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 6),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: The final result]

Comment: Thanks... But I thought about this. But you see, since the widget is going to be responsive and the text is going to be dynamic, this is going to be somewhat difficult. I can always calculate the width and substring the text for some specific number of characters and display this way. I shall wait for a 5 more days and accept this answer.