# Sizing flutter widgets based on a "sibling" (custom RenderStack)

Tags: flutter-layout

I'm trying to create an "underlay" (as opposed to overlay) widget that needs to size like the overlay widget. I can't use a Stack since it seems Stack requires its children to have a defined size. It also seems I can't use CustomMultiChildLayout since MultiChildLayoutDelegate doesn't support the container size from depending on the size of the children (per docs.)

That leaves me with MultiChildRenderObjectWidget for which I can't find a good sample anywhere.

The goal is to show a progress bar underneath a text label. The progress bar should automatically scale to the size of the text. These in turn are enclosed in a Column, and FittedBox set to scale down automatically. The FittedBox ensures the layout nicely adjusts to any screen width.

Any help hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question; CustomMultiChildLayout actually does work, and it's explained really well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483051/how-to-use-custommultichildlayout-customsinglechildlayout-in-flutter/59483482#59483482).