# Flutter ListView.builder follow certain Text element inside dynamically changing RichText widget

Tags: flutter, listview

I need ListView.builder to display list over RichText widget that is constantly being dynamically changed, in particular, over TextSpan(text: 'ListView.builder') as shown in images.

[image: ListView.builder follows the TextSpan(text: 'ListView.builder')]

[image: ListView.builder follows the TextSpan(text: 'ListView.builder')]

thought I could do that with Stack widget, by using MediaQuery.of(context), but couldn't find a way to do it.

Here: [How to use CustomMultiChildLayout & CustomSingleChildLayout in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483051/how-to-use-custommultichildlayout-customsinglechildlayout-in-flutter)
I found that CustomMultiChildLayout could be used to achieve that, from research I found online, it seems, Stack widget can't be used to dynamically change position on screen?

Answer in that another StackOverflow question is really extensive, but problem is that I am still a naab, and can't understand it without working code, there is code provided, but its rather just code snipets. Ive also cloned Clock project from that answer, but couldn't make it work, tried to add web to it and similar, but stuck on it.

In Clock project code, through find search, was able to locate only few CustomMultiChildLayout widgets there, even though, author says he used this widget in Clock project extensively. And from these few examples wasn't able to figure out how to do what I need.

Basically want similar behavior like this, when user writes word with error in it, box shows on screen right under word with error in it, with suggestion for correct word, just that I need list there instead of single word, and in RichText rather than in TextField
[image: Example of what I need]

Thank on your time

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewBuilderOverRichText extends StatefulWidget {
  ListViewBuilderOverRichText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListViewBuilderOverRichTextState createState() =>
      _ListViewBuilderOverRichTextState();
}

class _ListViewBuilderOverRichTextState
    extends State<ListViewBuilderOverRichText> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    print('_focusNode.dispose()');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
    final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[100, 500, 600];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListViev.builder over RichText'),
      ),
      body: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                text: TextSpan(
                  text:
                      'dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: '  ListView.builder',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18.0),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                // maxLines: 4,
                // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 80,
          left: 380,
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: entries.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      // color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
                      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
                    );
                  })),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made out solution out of different posts over internet that is looking really promising.

Couldn't figure out how to do it with CustomMultiChildLayout, and from my playing with it, it seems that that isn't really possible, at least for me.

Doing it with Stack widget, Im getting position of element in RichText by finding its Offset position, for this need to use Key, though TextSpan doesn't have Key property, so im using InkWell widget inside RichText instead (I presume I can turn off animations associated with it).

It works really well, ListTiles are following InkWell accordingly (need to add few lines of code to make it seamless).

Though still have big issue, can't get ListView.builder to display items that are outside of Text widget, can't wrap it in Extended() or Flexible() widget, getting error, incorrect use of parent widget, I presume that's because I use Stack widget and don't know what else to do. Please let me know if someone can solve this issue.

There are buttons on the page, so one can add or remove text, as to see it in action.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        // notice "hot reload" button
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: GetPosition()),
    );
  }
}

class GetPosition extends StatefulWidget {
  String changeText =
      'dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text dynamicaly changing text';
  @override
  _GetPositionState createState() => _GetPositionState();
}

class _GetPositionState extends State<GetPosition> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  double _x = 0, _y = 0;

  // this function is trigger when the user presses the floating button
  void _getOffset(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox? box = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    Offset position = box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    setState(() {
      _x = position.dx;
      _y = position.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[100, 200, 300, 500, 600];
    final List<String> entries = <String>[
      _x != null ? "X: $_x" : '',
      _y != null ? "Y: $_y" : '',
      _x != null ? 'Entry A' : '',
      _x != null ? 'Entry B' : '',
      _x != null ? 'EntryC' : ''
    ];
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
                  RichText(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: '${widget.changeText}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                      children: [
                        WidgetSpan(
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                            key: _key,
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              " ListView.builder",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: _y + 40,
                    left: _x + 50,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            itemCount: entries.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Container(
                                color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
                                child:
                                    // dense: true,
                                    // height: 300,

                                    // children: [
                                    Text(
                                  '${entries[index]}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18.0),
                                ),
                                // ],
                              );
                            });
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // randomPosition();
                              print(screenWidth);
                              _getOffset(_key);
                              widget.changeText = widget.changeText +
                                  ' dynamic text added dynamic text added dynamic text added dynamic text added dynamic text added dynamic text added';
                              // print(randomLeft);
                              // print(randomTop);
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: Text('Add some text')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print(screenWidth);
                            _getOffset(_key);
                            if (widget.changeText.length > 25) {
                              widget.changeText = widget.changeText
                                  .substring(25, widget.changeText.length - 1);
                            } else {
                              if (widget.changeText.length > 0) {
                                widget.changeText = widget.changeText
                                    .substring(0, widget.changeText.length - 1);
                              } else {}
                            }

                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: const Text('Delete some Text'),
                        )
                      ]),
                ]),
              ]);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: need to add "clipBehavior: Clip.none," to Stack widget to display Positioned widget outside of Stack widget