# How to give height based on available height for customWidget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a customWidget for showing data named CustomShowDataWidget, and this widget is used in many screens but with different available heights.. so how to apply height based on available screen height...

here is my custom widget

```
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
   ShowTransactionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 500,//-< I have given fixed height what I dont want...
      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            child: Text('Recent Transactions',style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 20
            ),),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Hello $index'),
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the one of the screen where I am using this widget

```
class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.70,

        ),
        ShowTransactionWidget(),

      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awaiting answer if anyone has...

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I have two screen, HomeScreen and NextScreen, in both screen I want to show all transactions...in first screen I have many other widgets which occupy half screen size and after that I am placing this transactionWidget... and in next screen I have full space for showing this transactionWidget...Hope it is clear now what I mean to...

Comment: In my ShowTransactionWidget I have given height of 500...instead of 500 I want to give available size of the screen...

Comment: Simple query...a widget should be occupy available height of the screen...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```dart
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShowTransactionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Recent Transactions",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const ListTile(
                    title: Text("Hello"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```dart
ShowTransactionWidget(),
```

Comment: this is what I dont want to count manually...it should occupy its own..is not there any other widget that count remaining space

Comment: Yes it worked ...but still I have some doubt...will apply code to my project and will let u know if I get any other issues...thank u very much

Comment: I thought LayoutBuilder is used for such situation..but it worked without it....at what situation LayoutBuilder is used...do u have any example to share with me? I can't learn with reading documents...I learn with examples

Comment: @IrfanGanatra I use `LayoutBuilder` for responsive. Code: https://pastebin.com/mRD3Z8py, https://pastebin.com/M4CF2pHr

Comment: My Car , hi sir.. can u check my question as I am confused in this concept :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446794/unexpected-output-while-using-get-put-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You want your widget `ShowTransactionWidget` to have a height which is relative to the available height given to it.

Okay, first, you must learn that in flutter, [Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints). So if your widget can be a part of other widgets, don't always expect it can take the size you want it to take.

After you learn that, you have multiple options:

- Use `LayoutBuilder` widget to wrap your `Container`. This widget will give you the available constraints to your widget, and you can use the max height to determine the height of your widget.

```
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ShowTransactionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
        return Container(
          height: maxHeight/2,
...
```

- Use the `MediaQuery` to get the size inside your `ShowTransactionWidget`, but you may want more information than the size of the screen as your widget might not be allowed to have the whole size of the screen, so this option might not fit all cases.

```
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ShowTransactionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size; // The size of the media in logical pixels (e.g, the size of the screen).
    return Container(
      height: size.height/2,
...
```

- Pass the max height to your `ShowTransactionWidget` in its constructor, and then define the height of the `Container` relative to that height

```
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  
  ShowTransactionWidget({Key? key, required this.height}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height, // passed from parent, this method of passing the height is useful when your child's height is always determined by the parent's height
...
```

- Use more complex widgets like [`CustomSingleChildLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483482/9142279).

Comment: Thanks....but do a favour can u apply some code to my given code for making what I want

Comment: @IrfanGanatra code added, and I highly recommend you read the linked article in the answer, it will help you alot understand how to work with constraints in flutter.