# unexpected output while using get.put in flutter

Tags: flutter

To make my point clear I have created this small code..

it looks like I missing to understand concept of byref and byval here..

and what does actually Get.put works.

I have commented the lines what made me confused

GetxController

```
class UserController extends GetxController  {
  List<UserModel> _userlist = [];

  UserModel? currentuser;


  UserController() {
     _userlist.add(UserModel(username: 'temp', password: 't123'));
  }

  List<UserModel> get getusers {
    return _userlist;
  }
}
```

this is main

```
void main()
{
  final uc1=Get.put(UserController());
  UserModel user1=UserModel(username: 'abc', password: 'a123');
  uc1.currentuser=user1;

  //showing print abc
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);


  final uc2=Get.put(UserController());
  UserModel user2=UserModel(username: 'xyz', password: 'x123');
  uc2.currentuser=user2;

  //showing printing result=xyz
  print(uc2.currentuser!.username);

  //showing printing result=xyz, instead of abc why?
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);

}
```

Comment: bcz you are init two time put method of getXController

Comment: Please check my answer its helpful for you. in simple lang :)

Answer (score 0):

**Because** you are using the put method two time
if you want to update a single instance then follow the below code:

```
void main()
{
  final uc1=Get.put(UserController());
  UserModel user1=UserModel(username: 'abc', password: 'a123');
  uc1.currentuser=user1;

  //showing print abc
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);

  UserController uc2 = Get.find();
  UserModel user2=UserModel(username: 'xyz', password: 'x123');
  uc2.currentuser=user2;

  //showing printing result=xyz
  print(uc2.currentuser!.username);

  //showing printing result=abc
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get.put` only puts a new instance when there isn't already one, (or the one that's there is marked as dirty). You can see it by digging deeper into the code. Ctrl + clicking the `put` method (in Android Studio at least) makes you able to see the implementation. The first step leads to

```
  S put<S>(S dependency,
          {String? tag,
          bool permanent = false,
          InstanceBuilderCallback<S>? builder}) =>
      GetInstance().put<S>(dependency, tag: tag, permanent: permanent);
```

then doing it on `put` again leads to

```
  S put<S>(
    S dependency, {
    String? tag,
    bool permanent = false,
    @deprecated InstanceBuilderCallback<S>? builder,
  }) {
    _insert(
        isSingleton: true,
        name: tag,
        permanent: permanent,
        builder: builder ?? (() => dependency));
    return find<S>(tag: tag);
  }
```

And digging into the `_insert` method gives:

```
  /// Injects the Instance [S] builder into the `_singleton` HashMap.
  void _insert<S>({
    bool? isSingleton,
    String? name,
    bool permanent = false,
    required InstanceBuilderCallback<S> builder,
    bool fenix = false,
  }) {
    final key = _getKey(S, name);

    if (_singl.containsKey(key)) {
      final dep = _singl[key];
      if (dep != null && dep.isDirty) {
        _singl[key] = _InstanceBuilderFactory<S>(
          isSingleton,
          builder,
          permanent,
          false,
          fenix,
          name,
          lateRemove: dep as _InstanceBuilderFactory<S>,
        );
      }
    } else {
      _singl[key] = _InstanceBuilderFactory<S>(
        isSingleton,
        builder,
        permanent,
        false,
        fenix,
        name,
      );
    }
  }
```

Here you can see that if it already exists and `isDirty` is true, or if it doesn't exist yet, only then it inserts a new instance. Now I'm not entirely sure when `isDirty` is set, but I believe it happens when you change routes in your app. So the second time you call `put` you are actually retrieving the one that is already put there before. Now if you want to have multiple instances you can use `Get.create(() => UserController());` followed by `Get.find` instead. Like:

```
void main()
{
  Get.create(() => UserController());
  UserController uc1 = Get.find();
  UserModel user1=UserModel(username: 'abc', password: 'a123');
  uc1.currentuser=user1;

  //showing print abc
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);


  UserController uc2 = Get.find();
  UserModel user2=UserModel(username: 'xyz', password: 'x123');
  uc2.currentuser=user2;

  //showing printing result=xyz
  print(uc2.currentuser!.username);

  //showing printing result=abc
  print(uc1.currentuser!.username);

}
```